# "Component c:multiselectpicklist does not exist", in VF for Multiselect

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am following tutorial from the link: http://sfdcintegration.blogspot.in/2015/08/multiselect-picklist-in-visualforce-page.html . In this example, I haven't done any custom changes yet, but trying to execute the same, but see below error.

**Error**

```
Component c:multiselectpicklist does not exist
```

**MultiselectController**

```
public with sharing class MultiselectController {
    // SelectOption lists for public consumption
    public SelectOption[] leftOptions { get; set; }
    public SelectOption[] rightOptions { get; set; }

 public SelectOption[] selectedContacts { get; set; }
    public SelectOption[] allContacts { get; set; }

 public String message { get; set; }

 public MultiselectController() {
        selectedContacts = new List<SelectOption>();

        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Name, Id FROM Contact];    
        allContacts = new List<SelectOption>();
        for ( Contact c : contacts ) {
            allContacts.add(new SelectOption(c.Id, c.Name));
        }
    }

    // Parse &-separated values and labels from value and 
    // put them in option
    private void setOptions(SelectOption[] options, String value) {
        options.clear();
        String[] parts = value.split('&');
        for (Integer i=0; i<parts.size()/2; i++) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(parts[i*2], 'UTF-8'), 
              EncodingUtil.urlDecode(parts[(i*2)+1], 'UTF-8')));
        }
    }

    // Backing for hidden text field containing the options from the
    // left list
    public String leftOptionsHidden { get; set {
           leftOptionsHidden = value;
           setOptions(leftOptions, value);
        }
    }

    // Backing for hidden text field containing the options from the
    // right list
    public String rightOptionsHidden { get; set {
           rightOptionsHidden = value;
           setOptions(rightOptions, value);
        }
    }

 public PageReference save() {
        message = 'Selected Contacts: ';
        Boolean first = true;
        for ( SelectOption so : selectedContacts ) {
            if (!first) {
                message += ', ';
            }
            message += so.getLabel() + ' (' + so.getValue() + ')';
            first = false;
        }

        return null;       
    }
}
```

**MultiselectControllerVFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="MultiselectController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock title="Contacts">
            <c:multiselectpicklist leftlabel="Available Contacts" leftoption="{!allContacts}" rightlabel="Selected Contacts" rightoption="{!selectedContacts}" size="14" width="150px"></c:multiselectpicklist>
            <apex:pageblockbuttons>
           </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and **MultiselectControllerVFComponent**

```
<apex:component controller="MultiselectController">
  <apex:attribute description="Label on left listbox." name="leftLabel" required="true" type="String"></apex:attribute>
  <apex:attribute description="Label on right listbox." name="rightLabel" required="true" type="String"></apex:attribute>
  <apex:attribute description="Size of listboxes." name="size" required="true" type="Integer"></apex:attribute>
  <apex:attribute description="Width of listboxes." name="width" required="true" type="String"></apex:attribute>
  <apex:attribute default="true" description="Should Up/Down buttons be displayed or not." name="showUpDownButtons" required="false" type="Boolean"></apex:attribute>

  <apex:attribute assignto="{!leftOptions}" description="Options list for left listbox." name="leftOption" required="true" type="SelectOption[]"></apex:attribute>
  <apex:attribute assignto="{!rightOptions}" description="Options list for right listbox." name="rightOption" required="true" type="SelectOption[]"></apex:attribute>

  <apex:outputpanel id="multiselectPanel" layout="block" styleclass="duelingListBox">
    <table class="layout">
      <tbody>
<tr>
          <td class="selectCell"><apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleclass="selectTitle">
              <!-- 
                Visualforce prepends the correct prefix to the outputLabel's 
                'for' attribute
              -->
              <apex:outputlabel for="multiselectPanel:leftList" value="{!leftLabel}"></apex:outputlabel>
            </apex:outputpanel>

            <select class="multilist" id="{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:leftList" multiple="multiple" size="0" style="width: {!width};">
              <apex:repeat value="{!leftOptions}" var="option">
                <option value="{!option.value}">{!option.label}</option>
              </apex:repeat>
            </select>

          </td>
          <td class="buttonCell"><apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleclass="text">Add</apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleclass="text">
              <apex:outputlink id="btnRight" value="javascript:moveSelectedOptions('{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:leftList', 
                  '{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:rightList', '{!$Component.leftHidden}', 
                  '{!$Component.rightHidden}');">
                <apex:image alt="Add" styleclass="rightArrowIcon" title="Add" value="/s.gif"></apex:image>
              </apex:outputlink>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleclass="text">
              <apex:outputlink id="btnLeft" value="javascript:moveSelectedOptions('{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:rightList', 
                  '{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:leftList', '{!$Component.rightHidden}', 
                  '{!$Component.leftHidden}');">
                <apex:image alt="Remove" styleclass="leftArrowIcon" title="Remove" value="/s.gif"></apex:image>
              </apex:outputlink>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleclass="duelingText">Remove</apex:outputpanel>
          </td>
          <td class="selectCell"><apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleclass="selectTitle">
              <apex:outputlabel for="multiselectPanel:rightList" value="{!rightLabel}"></apex:outputlabel>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <select class="multilist" id="{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:rightList" multiple="multiple" size="0" style="width: {!width};">
              <apex:repeat value="{!rightOptions}" var="option">
                <option value="{!option.value}">{!option.label}</option>
              </apex:repeat>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="buttonCell"><apex:outputpanel layout="block" rendered="{!showUpDownButtons}" styleclass="text">Up</apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" rendered="{!showUpDownButtons}" styleclass="text">
              <apex:outputlink id="upBtn" value="javascript:slideSelectedOptionsUp('{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:rightList', 
                  '{!$Component.rightHidden}');">
                <apex:image alt="Up" styleclass="upArrowIcon" title="Up" value="/s.gif"></apex:image>
              </apex:outputlink>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" rendered="{!showUpDownButtons}" styleclass="text">
              <apex:outputlink id="downBtn" value="javascript:slideSelectedOptionsDown('{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:rightList', 
                  '{!$Component.rightHidden}');">
                <apex:image alt="Down" styleclass="downArrowIcon" title="Down" value="/s.gif"></apex:image>
              </apex:outputlink>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" rendered="{!showUpDownButtons}" styleclass="text">Down</apex:outputpanel>
          </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
<apex:inputhidden id="leftHidden" value="{!leftOptionsHidden}"></apex:inputhidden>
    <apex:inputhidden id="rightHidden" value="{!rightOptionsHidden}"></apex:inputhidden>
  </apex:outputpanel>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (!buildOutputString) {
      // Create a string from the content of a listbox
      var buildOutputString = function(listBox, hiddenInput) {
        var str = '';

        for ( var x = 0; x < listBox.options.length; x++) {
          str += encodeURIComponent(listBox.options[x].value) + '&'
              + encodeURIComponent(listBox.options[x].text) + '&';
        }
        str.length--;

        hiddenInput.value = str.slice(0, -1);
      }
    }

    if (!moveSelectedOptions) {
      // Move the selected options in the idFrom listbox to the idTo
      // listbox, updating the corresponding strings in idHdnFrom and
      // idHdnTo
      var moveSelectedOptions = function(idFrom, idTo, idHdnFrom, idHdnTo) {
        listFrom = document.getElementById(idFrom);
        listTo = document.getElementById(idTo);

        for ( var x = 0; x < listTo.options.length; x++) {
          listTo.options[x].selected = false;
        }

        for ( var x = 0; x < listFrom.options.length; x++) {
          if (listFrom.options[x].selected == true) {
            listTo.appendChild(listFrom.options[x]);
            x--;
          }
        }

        listTo.focus();

        buildOutputString(listFrom, document.getElementById(idHdnFrom));
        buildOutputString(listTo, document.getElementById(idHdnTo));
      }
    }

    if (!slideSelectedOptionsUp) {
      // Slide the selected options in the idList listbox up by one position,
      // updating the corresponding string in idHidden
      var slideSelectedOptionsUp = function(idList, idHidden) {
        listBox = document.getElementById(idList);

        var len = listBox.options.length;

        if (len > 0 && listBox.options[0].selected == true) {
          return;
        }

        for ( var x = 1; x < len; x++) {
          if (listBox.options[x].selected == true) {
            listBox.insertBefore(listBox.options[x],
                listBox.options[x - 1]);
          }
        }

        listBox.focus();

        buildOutputString(listBox, document.getElementById(idHidden));
      }
    }

    if (!slideSelectedOptionsDown) {
      // Slide the selected options in the idList listbox down by one position,
      // updating the corresponding string in idHidden
      var slideSelectedOptionsDown = function(idList, idHidden) {
        listBox = document.getElementById(idList);

        var len = listBox.options.length;

        if (len > 0 && listBox.options[len - 1].selected == true) {
          return;
        }

        for ( var x = listBox.options.length - 2; x >= 0; x--) {
          if (listBox.options[x].selected == true) {
            listBox.insertBefore(listBox.options[x + 1],
                listBox.options[x]);
          }
        }

        listBox.focus();

        buildOutputString(listBox, document.getElementById(idHidden));
      }
    }

    // initialize the string representations
    buildOutputString(document.getElementById('{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:leftList'), 
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.leftHidden}'));
    buildOutputString(document.getElementById('{!$Component.multiselectPanel}:rightList'), 
        document.getElementById('{!$Component.rightHidden}'));
  </script>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: Double check you have saved it and that the name matches. Maybe you tried to save the component and got an error you did not notice or miskeyed the name

Comment: I am unable to save `MultiselectControllerVFPage` only, other files are saved.

Comment: I assumed your names were examples. If they are the actual names of the component then you need to use MultiselectControllerVFComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohk, so I see the issue, your file name looks different than you used, please use below code it will work.

```
<apex:page controller="MultiselectController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock title="Contacts">
            <c:multiselectcontrollervfcomponent leftlabel="Available Contacts" leftoption="{!allContacts}"
                                   rightlabel="Selected Contacts" rightoption="{!selectedContacts}"
                                   size="14" width="150px">

            </c:multiselectcontrollervfcomponent>
            <apex:pageblockbuttons>
           </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```